# Extracting adjusted means for lme function

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I'm running a model like this:

```
model<-lme(Juice~1+Fruit ,random=list(Place=pdIdent(~1)), method="REML",
                           control=lmeControl(niterEM=150 ,msMaxIter=200), na.action=na.omit,
                           data=customData, keep.data=FALSE)
```

And I want to extract the adjusted mean of Juice for every Fruit.
I've found some solutions involving `lsmean()` on `lmerTest` package but it throws an error saying:

> The model is not linear mixed effects model

So, kind of clueless here.

For a reproducible example (this is how my data looks btw):

```
Fruit=c(sort(rep(1:40,5)),sort(rep(1:40,5)))
Juice=c(rnorm(200, mean=15:25),rnorm(200, mean=13:23))
Place=c(rep("A",200), rep("B",200))

customData=data.frame(Fruit,Juice,Place)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `lsmeans()` (`lsmeans()` is now deprecated in favor of `lsmeansLT()`)? I'm guessing these functions might only work for model objects produced by `lmer` from the `lme4` package, and not on objects produced by `lme` from the `nlme` package.

Answer (score 0):

As @eipi10 already stated lsmeans() does not work with objects produced by the lme4 package. The lsmeans library might give you what you want:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(model, "Fruit")
```

Comment: I suggest using the new **emmeans** package, which is the continuation of **lsmeans**